# Precomputing AABBs for object instances

Tags: math, matrix, rendering

I have a number of models in my game and I render instances of these objects. I am supplied with the min and max of the untransformed model. These models are then scaled, rotated and translated. I am looking for a way to rotate translate and scale these positions for the scaling, I'll first do this in model space. Then I want to rotate the min and max around the origin. Finally, I will translate these to their actual place in the world.

I am confused about the rotation. These points are vectors. Do I create a matrix for these objects like I do when I render them and just multiply the min and max by the matrix? I also read something about having to update an AABB every frame. Is this true? I'd just like to creeate it once at the start and then use it with my frustum.

Comment: Perhaps http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6053522/how-to-recalculate-axis-aligned-bounding-box-after-translate-rotate can help you.

Comment: If you're not forced to use an AABB, you could also use a bounding sphere, which is invariant to rotations.